# How to use variables in transform filter

Tags: vega-lite

I have a filter inside my transform.

{"filter": {"field": "_source.activity_time", "gte": {{variable}} }}

activity time is in this format:  2019-07-02T07:36:29+00:00

This is not working

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you with your issue. Can you please include a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work. It just needed to be added to the mustache js renderer.